# using if, elif, else logic in a function to define a dataframe column--why can't I use str.contains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe column using a function using if/elif/else. A simplified example of my code is below. The main difference is the real code adds at least 20 different elif statements--hence, although I might be able to use nested np.where() or np.select(), I would prefer not to.

```
def func(row):
    if row['condition']==True:
        if row['summary'].str.contains('hi|there',case=False):
            return 'hi_there'
        else:
            return 'Other'
    else:
        if row['summary'].str.contains('goodbye|you',case=False):
            return 'goodbye_you'
        else:
            return 'Other'


df['newcolumn'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
```

I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'.
```

Is it possible to create my column using this method, but with a few additional tweaks? If it's not possible in Python, why?

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in `row` at key `'summary'` is a String, which has no attribute `.str`. Try getting rid of `.str` and see if it works.

Comment: I removed the str from both instances and got a similar error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Comment: python has no .contains you need to use `in` like this `'substring' in 'your_string'`

Answer (score 0):

You use the 'str' to access vectorized string functions on a column. With apply you iterate trough every row.

You can rewrite your function that you use within your apply. In this case you need something like this:

```
'hi' in row['summary'].lower()
```

or a regex as you did

```
import re
...
re.search('hi|there', row['summary'], re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Better** I think would be to actually use those vectorized functions as you started, just not within the apply, but on the dataframe columns directly

```
    df['new_column'] = 'Other'
    df.loc[(row['condition']==True)&(row['summary'].str.contains('hi|there',case=False)),'new_column'] = 'hi_there'
    df.loc[(row['condition']==False)&(row['summary'].str.contains('goodbye|you',case=False)),'new_column'] = 'goodbye_you'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first option and got this error: `NameError: name 'lower' is not defined`. It did work when I created a lowercase version of summary and changed it to `'hi' in lower(row['summary'])`. Good to see your other alternatives too!

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, lower is supposed to be used differently. I updated the answer.